# Update android view upon changing child view visibility immediatelly

Tags: android

I have an view, that is a RelativeLayout. Inside that layout, there is an image, that has visibility set to gone by default. What I want to achieve is to change visibility to visible programmatically and after that make a view snapshot, draw it to canvas.

```
    View icon = v.findViewById(android.R.id.icon2);
    if (icon != null) {
        icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        v.invalidate();
        v.forceLayout();
        icon.invalidate();
        icon.refreshDrawableState();
    }
```

....

```
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    mFloatBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

The resulting bitmap does not contain changes `icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`. How should I invalidate the view immediatelly? Neither of the methods I used after `icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` did not work.

Comment: You know that you can draw view to any canvas you desire? By calling public method `draw(Canvas)`? Also, with this approach you don't need to invalidate view or redo layout (usually).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't actually become visible until after it has gone through an onMeasure and an onDraw.  Until onMeasure it doesn't know its height, until onDraw it doesn't have a cache.  You're going to have to do this after the draw occurs.  There's no way to make it happen immediately.